# Force Stop in setData Command

Tags: android, android-intent, forceclose

goto1 function is called successfully but
android process stopped working...
m not able to get the bug in this code..
but it seems to me that

"data.setData " line is creating a  problem..
if I remove this line android.process does not freezes..
Does anyone know the exact solution to this problem

```
public class scndactivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.next);
        Toast t=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On Create",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();

        TextView id=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            id.setText("this is second activity");
    }

    public void goto1(View v)
    {
        Intent data=new Intent();
        //startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN"));
        finish();
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        EditText editText1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        data.setData(Uri.parse(editText1.getText().toString()));
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hi ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the purpose of `goto1` ? also `Uri.parse(...)` may throw an exception depending on whats inside editText1...

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing your indentation (StackOverflow uses 4-columns tabs). Also, it's good Java style to capitalize class names, e.g. ScndActivity

Comment: How do you mean "freeze"? Whole device freezes? You get an "Application Not Responding" (ANR) error? Is there anything in the logcat?  What are the context of your **editText1**? At a guess, I'd say try it without the **finish()** call. But above all, show us the logcat output.

Comment: goto1 function is called on the action of a button

Comment: freeze means that application stops responding..I have to force stop that application

Comment: @EdwardFalk: Right Edward.I'll remember it next time. Thnks

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you should call `setResult` before calling `finish`, and make sure that the text in `editText1` is in a valid Uri format.